Recommended fit, Timefold
Im trying to use the recommended fit in Timefold and need to set 4 planningvariables, I would like to use a combination of cartesian and sequential moves in the Constructions Heuristic.
But i can only get it to use the first move of the CS no matter which i place first , it will be the only one that is run, any other move-selections are ignored. So I am only ably to set all 4 variables using a combined cartesian product selection, which does not scale well. is this a limitation of the API or is there a way around it. ?
Also it seem the pickearlytype is ignores here as well, as i get all possible combinations returned even if valid solutions are found earlier in returned result list ?
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <constraintProviderClass>MyConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <termination>
    <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>180</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>

  <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
    <cartesianProductMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <valueSelector variableName="timeBlock">
          <filterClass>TimeBlockSelectionFilter</filterClass>
        </valueSelector>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <valueSelector variableName="worker">
          <filterClass>NoNullVariableAndNoKompetencer</filterClass>
        </valueSelector>
      </changeMoveSelector>
    </cartesianProductMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <valueSelector variableName="room">
        <filterClass>NoNullVariable</filterClass>
      </valueSelector>
    </changeMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <valueSelector variableName="assistant">
        <filterClass>NoNullVariable</filterClass>
      </valueSelector>
    </changeMoveSelector>
    <forager>
      <pickEarlyType>FIRST_FEASIBLE_SCORE_OR_NON_DETERIORATING_HARD</pickEarlyType>
    </forager>
  </constructionHeuristic>
</solver>


Recommended Fit does look at the configuration of Construction Heuristics, but it only uses a small portion of it. It can not be configured to do what you're trying to.
This is just one consequence of attempting to model a problem with multiple planning variables. Even though it is possible, there are places where it is not practical, this being one of them. We generally recommend designing models with the smallest possible number of planning variables, ideally one.

Ok, thx. So if I want more control for instance to not continue searching if enough feasible recommendations are found, I could submit smaller versions of the real solution to only get sections of the full recommendations, making it possible to end early if my criteria’s are met.
